# Minimise the sum of pairwise distances between labelled points in a metric space subject to covering some set of labels

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, algorithms, np-complete

I would like to know the name of the following problem. I assume it is NP-hard, but a link to a proof of such would also be appreciated.

Say we have some set of points in a metric space $S = \{p_1,...,p_n\}$. There are some labels $L=\{l_1,...,l_m\}$. Point are labelled by a surjective function $f_l: S \rightarrow L$. Find the subset of points C such that:

- $\{f_l(c): c\in{}C\}=L$ (L is covered)
- $Q=\sum_{c,c'\in{}C}{d(c, c')}$ is minimised (the points are as close as possible)

  - Note that this implies $|C| = |L|$, that C is of minimal size
  - Also note we can assume $c\neq{}c'$ without loss of generality since $d(p_i, p_i) = 0$

Comment: Surely the second condition is superfluous: if you have a covering set with a duplicated label, you can reduce the sum in condition 3 by deleting any point whose label is a duplicate. I know this doesn't help much, but ...

Comment: One more thing, which gives me some small hope that the problem might be easier than it appears. The sum in the last condition, which I'll call $Q$, can be rewritten as $Q = |L| \cdot \sum_{s \in C} d(s, u)$, where $u$ is the average of $C$. [I assume in that last sum, you meant to say that $s_1, s_2$ were in $C$, not $S$, or the sum is independent of the chocie of $C$, and the problem becomes very easy.]

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the corrections.